# Change Pager-ItemsPerPage over URL argument

Tags: 7, views

I use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to get Nodes in JSON format via REST service. I can switch the pages with;

`http://myside/?q=my/path&page=1`

but I want to change the limit of one page like;

`http://myside/?q=my/path&limit=100`.

Has anybody a good solution or one alternative.

Answer (score 4):

there is default option in views pager as "EXPOSED OPTIONS" while adding pager to views.

You can add range output.

[image]

So you can show per page option. set results using URL argument like http://example.com/path?limit=100

[image]

Comment: clever answer :)